# Why does mail popup occasionally?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

The mail app in OS X 10.11.1 seems to have a bug which I would really like to fix because it is annoying. Sometimes when the main interface windows is minimized in the dock, it will maximize itself for no apparent reason. I think it might do this when it checks for mail or something because when it maximizes, the "offline" symbol appears next to various mail accounts. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: How comfortable are you at looking over log files. It's going to be messy to check about a dozen different files and looking at time stamps, but you could enable logging in Mail if you want to track this down.

Comment: @bmike I have never looked at a log file. As far as that goes, I am only familiar with web development.

Comment: Open Window - Connection Doctor, tick the log button and then show logs. You'll be overwhelmed and also might need to use the console app to look at "all messages" or the system log to figure out the issue. My guess is that it's a network error causing some UI element to summon the window, but I haven't seen that on any app - self un minimizing, so I could be way off base.

Comment: @Eliza https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/344223/

Comment: This also happens in catalina